# drop down select in form does not save data to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

Ruby newbie here, so be gentle please.

I added a dropdown menu to my form but when I submit it, it doesn't get saved to the database. All the other field do work and I'm making the dropdown on a similar way as the other fields.

I also added the columns to the db with the following commands:

> `rails g migration AddStatusToIdeas status:enum`
>
> `rake db:migrate`

**app/models/idea.rb**

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  # {attr_accessor :Status}
  enum status: [ :Draft, :Published]
end
```

**app/views/ideas/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@idea) do |f| %>
    <% if @idea.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@idea.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this idea from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @idea.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :description %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :status %><br>
      <%= f.select(:status, options_for_select([['Draft', 'Draft'],['Published', 'Published']])) %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :picture %><br>
      <%= f.file_field :picture %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you post the log file, with the related request?

Comment: @Зелёный: http://pastebin.com/WRG91tPi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unpermitted param `status`:

> Started POST "/ideas" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-29 12:20:39 +0300
>   Processing by IdeasController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"pVM48/l0mTKe48pfg6TBytPO4eMNRmNBm1aDaHUvfQo=",
>   "idea"=>{"name"=>"test for SO", "description"=>"test for SO",
>   "status"=>"Published"}, "commit"=>"Create Idea"}   User Load
>   (0.0ms) SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" =
>   2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 10 **Unpermitted parameters:
>   status**   (0.0ms)  begin transaction   SQL
>   (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "ideas" ("created_at", "description",
>   "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["created_at",
>   "2016-03-29 09:20:39.034503"], ["description", "test for SO"],
>   ["name", "test for SO"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-29 09:20:39.034503"]]
>    (8.7ms)  commit transaction Redirected to
>   http://localhost:3000/ideas/9 Completed 302 Found in 24ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 9.2ms)

Fix your controller permit params method.

```
def idea_params
  params.require(:idea).permit(:name, :description, :status, :picture)
end
```

Comment: `params.require(:idea).permit(:name, :description, :status, :picture)` fixed it, thank you